# how to validate if string is date with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to parse if string is valid date. I tried everything in the web, and nothing works. I know that the question is asked multiple times before, but even in the threads that say they solved the problem, does,not work for me. I start to asking myself is there a way at all.
I will send my code here. I have three text box: one for day, one for month and year, and on form submit I need to check if they form valid date.

```
<html> 
  <head> 
  <title>Simple Form Validation</title> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">

         jQuery.validator.addMethod(
               "customDateValidator",
                function(value, element) {
                 var concateDate;
                 concateDate= $("#day").val() + "/" + $("#month").val() + "/" + $("#year").val();        

                    var rslt= (Date.parseExact(concateDate, "d/M/yyyy") );
                    if(isNaN(rslt))
                      return false;
                    else
                     return true;               
                    },
                    "Please enter a valid date"
                );
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
      $("#form1").validate({ 
        rules: { 

        year: { 
          customDateValidator: true 
        } 
        }, 
        messages: { 
          year: "Please enter valid datum." 
        } 
      }); 
    }); 
  </script>  

  </head> 

  <body> 
    <form id="form1" method="post" action=""> 
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Day *</span><input type="text" name="day" id="day" /></div> 
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Month *</span><input type="text" name="month" id="month" /></div> 
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Year</span><input type="text" name="year" id="year" /></div> 
      <div class="form-row"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div> 
    </form> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I'm doing it and it works well.

```
rules: {
  month: { required: true },
  day: { required: true },
  year: { required: true, date_check: function(){ return $("#month").val()+'/'+$("#day").val()+'/'+$("#year").val() } }
}

jQuery.validator.addMethod("date_check",function(a,b,c){
    month = c.substring(0,2)-1;
    day = c.substring(3,5);
    year = c.substring(6,10);
    mSeconds = (new Date(year, month, day)).getTime();
    objDate = new Date();
    objDate.setTime(mSeconds);
    if(objDate.getFullYear() != year || objDate.getMonth() != month || objDate.getDate() != day) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}, "Please provide a valid date.");
```

Comment: But it doesn't support for globalization. OP is using dd/mm/yyyy and in this answer you're using mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Then modify it for your use? It's not too difficult.