# Best way to validate date string format via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I found a lot of links to validate string if it is a date.

Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760032/how-to-validate-if-string-is-date-with-jquery) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse).

But anyway I cannot figure out how to validate if we have this thing:

**6/6/2012** where first **6** is month and the second  **6** is days

and also if user input it like that:

**06/06/2012**

Any clue how it could be done in a proper way?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here, this should work with any date format with 4 digit year and any delimiter. I extracted it from my plugin [Ideal Forms](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms) which validates dates and much more.

```
var isValidDate = function (value, userFormat) {
  var

  userFormat = userFormat || 'mm/dd/yyyy', // default format

  delimiter = /[^mdy]/.exec(userFormat)[0],
  theFormat = userFormat.split(delimiter),
  theDate = value.split(delimiter),

  isDate = function (date, format) {
    var m, d, y
    for (var i = 0, len = format.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (/m/.test(format[i])) m = date[i]
      if (/d/.test(format[i])) d = date[i]
      if (/y/.test(format[i])) y = date[i]
    }
    return (
      m > 0 && m < 13 &&
      y && y.length === 4 &&
      d > 0 && d <= (new Date(y, m, 0)).getDate()
    )
  }

  return isDate(theDate, theFormat)

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a regular expression.

```
var dateRegEx = /^(0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$/

console.log("06/06/2012".match(dateRegEx) !== null) // true
console.log("6/6/2012".match(dateRegEx) !== null) // true
console.log("6/30/2012".match(dateRegEx) !== null) // true
console.log("30/06/2012".match(dateRegEx) !== null) // false
```

[Learn about RegEx.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy/datemmddyyyy.html)

### Edit - A Disclaimer

As @elclanrs pointed out, this only validates the string's **format**, and not the actual date, which means that dates like February 31st would pass.  However, since the OP only asks "*to validate date string format*," I'll keep this answer here because for some, it might be all you need.

As a note, the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date) that the OP was using, also only validates format.

Finally, for those wondering, if you needed to validate the date, and not just the format, this regular expression would have **~2% rate of failure** over the domain of *(1-12)/(1-31)/(1900-2099)* date strings.  Please don't use this in Mission Critical code for JPL.

Comment: This won't do it for every case ie. `console.log("11/31/2012".match(dateRegEx)) // true`

Comment: @elclanrs Um...isn't that a valid (M)M/(D)D/YYYY date string? Are you saying it should return false?

Comment: Well, November doesn't have 31 days...so yeah I guess it should return false.

Comment: @elclanrs - Aha! good catch...sometimes it's easy to get ahead of oneself.