# JS RegEx for date & name rules

Tags: javascript, regex, date, rule

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to validate date string format via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218181/best-way-to-validate-date-string-format-via-jquery)

Date validation : dd/mm/yyyy or d/m/yyyy

```
/^({|()?[0-9]{1,2}\/([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}))+$/
```

But how to set max day, max month, year rules ? (max day = 31, max month = 12, year = 1900-2012)

---

Name validation :

```
/[a-zA-Zøæå]{2,40}$/
```

Rules : Letter a-z A-Z , Ø,Æ,Å (min=2, max=40)

Can you review this regex rule ? + this dosen`t work

Comment: The solution for dates is not to use regex. Take a look at my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218181/best-way-to-validate-date-string-format-via-jquery/11218271#11218271

Comment: Name validation? Looking at your expression Jean-Michelle O'Connel would not be a valid name. A name _can_ contain an apostrophe, a dash, spaces and dots.

Comment: Oh, so i can use only name.length  ?

Comment: Also avoiding special chars like /%$, numbers & so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Best way to validate date string format via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218181/best-way-to-validate-date-string-format-via-jquery/11218271#11218271)