# Regular expressions for javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i need a regular expression for an expire date for a visa in the layout MM/DD/YYYY i used

```
var expire = /(\d{2})+\/(\d{2})+\/(\d{4})/
```

and i know \d is for digit and the {4} allows for exactly 4 digits so im not really sure what im doing wrong here.
thanks for the help

Comment: Isn't expiration date just `MM/YYYY`?

Comment: You should get rid of the `+` operators after the first two two-digit groups.

Comment: Funny, [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) says `(\d{2})+\/(\d{2})+\/(\d{4})` matches.

Comment: @Whymarrh: why shouldn't it? It would match `1111111111/11/1111` as well though

Comment: The answer below says the `+` sign causes problems.

Comment: @Whymarrh: it would give false positives, but still it would match what it expected to match

Comment: Regular expressions for dates is not the best idea because you're validating a format not a _valid date_. Check my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218181/best-way-to-validate-date-string-format-via-jquery/11218271#11218271) if you want to validate the format as well as the date, meaning that `11/31/2012` would be invalid although it has a valid format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works for MM/DD/YYYY:

```
(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(19|20)\d\d
```

Or this one for DD/MM/YYYY:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(19|20)\d\d
```

Although, they do not cover dates like 31/02/2012...

Comment: "Although, they do not cover dates like 31/02/2012..." --- so, any reason to overcomplicate if you need to perform additional check anyway? Why not create trivial regex and polish it with thorough check on correctness separately

Comment: Wouldn't it be more performant to cover it in the regex itself instead of performing another check after?

Comment: you still need to perform check, don't you? `31/02/2012` would match your regex and it's not a correct date.

Answer (score 5):

It should be:

```
var expire = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/;
```

The `+` signs are causing the problems.

Comment: Personally I'd save 2 characters with `\d\d` for the month and day :-)

Comment: Yeah, that would make the regex 2 characters shorter!