# validate date pattern

Tags: javascript

i need a javascript method to validate a date pattern looks like this Jan 14, 2012

so far i am not sure which regex to use for this pattern as it is not standard date such as 14/01/2012 or 01/14/2012 or 01-04-2012..i tried to do something like this for early startes to split them up but ending i received a total split.

here is my split code

```
 function validateDate(date){
   var test = date.replace(",","");
   alert(test);
  var split = test.split("");
  for(i=0;i<split.length;i++){
      alert(split[i]);
   }
  alert("total length "+split.length);
}
```

Comment: Can you give more input examples?

Comment: i have a date input format which looks like this Jan 14, 2012 so i would like to validate this field to make sure that user are adding those date in a correct format. but this kind of date are not standard so is hard to do validation i guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) and particullary its [parsing functionnality](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). Something like :

```
moment("Jan 14, 2012", "MMM DD YYYY").isValid();
```

Comment: Hmm, so let's just load another 5K minified framework instead of using the 5 lines I posted :}

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}\s[0-9]{1,2},\s[0-9]{4}$
```

This will work for any date with month of three char, with comma after day, and 4 digit year, in that order

Comment: Feb 29, 2011 is valid in your case

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec), [0-3]?\d (\d\d)?\d\d
```

Please fill free to play with this expression to tune it up

Answer (score 0):

You could convert that format to the format you want. All you need to do is extract the parts:

```
function formatDate( dateStr ) {
  var date = new Date( dateStr ),
      m = date.getMonth() + 1,
      d = date.getDate(),
      y = date.getFullYear();
  return m +'/'+ d +'/'+ y; // you can use any format here
}

console.log( formatDate( 'Jan 14, 2012' ) ); //=> '1/14/2012'
```

Then you can use the new string with this function: [Best way to validate date string format via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218181/best-way-to-validate-date-string-format-via-jquery/11218271#11218271). That will effectively validate a date so "Feb 29, 2011" won't validate for example as mplungjan points out.

Usage:

```
if ( isValidDate( formatDate( 'Jan 14, 2012' ) ) ) {
  // valid
} else {
  // not valid
}
```

Comment: Feb 29, 2011 is valid in your case

Comment: It won't validate, follow [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218181/best-way-to-validate-date-string-format-via-jquery/11218271#11218271) for date validation. It'll work correctly once you pass the right format. Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/jeJxr/

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid string to pass to the date object

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/K6bca/)

```
var monthNames = "Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec".split(",");
function isvalid(str) {
  var d = new Date(str);
  var dateParts = str.split(" ");
  return monthNames[d.getMonth()]===dateParts[0] &&
         d.getDate()===parseInt(dateParts[1],10) &&
         d.getFullYear()===parseInt(dateParts[2],10);
}      
alert(isvalid("Jan 14, 2012"));
alert(isvalid("Feb 29, 2011"));
```

​