# get calender on button click in html and fill text filed with selected date

Tags: javascript, html, validation, date

I trying to validate a text field whether the entered input type is in date pattern or not. I seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835763/validate-date-pattern) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177975/how-to-validate-date-with-format-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript) but no result. So I want to get  calender on button click and fill text filed with selected date. How to validate this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: please refer to the datepicker plugin in jQuery. that will help you a lot - http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: @Murtaza Thanks for the quick response. I'll try and let you know

Comment: @Murtaza Thanks a lot its working like champ. It should be acceptable one if it is an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working for me try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```