# javascript date validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I've copied and modified a js date validator - from ( http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/validatedate.shtml )

I'm using it as part of a jquery modal form, it doesn't let me get past the first criteria..
even though the value is put in form the datepicker jquery UI

```
function checkDate( d, n ){
        if ( d.val().length > 0 ) {
            var validformat = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/; //Basic check for format validity
            if ( !validformat.test( d.value ) ) {
                d.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                updateTips( n + " must be a valid date." );
                return false;
            } else { //Detailed check for valid date ranges
                var monthfield = d.value.split( "/" )[0]
                var dayfield = d.value.split( "/" )[1]
                var yearfield = d.value.split( "/" )[2]
                var dayobj = new Date( yearfield, monthfield-1, dayfield )
                if ( ( dayobj.getMonth()+1 != monthfield ) || ( dayobj.getDate() != dayfield ) || ( dayobj.getFullYear() != yearfield ) ) {
                    d.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                    updateTips( "Invalid Day, Month, or Year range detected. Please correct and submit again." + n + " must be a valid date." );
                    return false;
                } 
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

when the value of 12/25/2012 is entered it returns... "Notification Date must be a valid date."
from the updateTips( n + " must be a valid date." ); line...

help please...

Comment: `12/25/2012` is a valid date ?

Comment: ^ The end of the world is before that, so I'd say no, it's not.

Comment: Try my answer to this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218181/best-way-to-validate-date-string-format-via-jquery/11218271#11218271

Comment: @elclanrs - i'm confused by what u r returning in that function...

Comment: @jpmyob: it returns `true` or `false` if the date is valid/invalid.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `d` is. Is it a DOM node? Then you can't call `.val()` on it. Is it a jQuery wrapper object? Then accessing its `.value` property will likely result in `undefined`, and the stringification of that value does not match your format.

Use some more variables, like

```
var value = d.val(); // to test length, regex and use in split
…
var parts = value.split("/"); // to get year, month and day part
```

Comment: sorry - d is passed in value...

the call looks like this:
    bValid = bValid && checkDate( notification_date, "Notification Date" );
Where notification_date is the field name