# Javascript date validation passing through more than wanted

Tags: javascript, validation, date

```
var chkdate=document.getElementById('date');
var dateformat=/^[0-9]{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]){2}/;

if(!dateformat.test(chkdate.value))
{
    alert("Please format the date in yyyy-mm-dd format.");
    return false;
}
```

and the html:

```
<form name="test" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" placeholder="First Last" name="name" id="name"><br />
Date: <input type="text" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="date" id="date"><br />
Number: <input type="integer" placeholder="Any integer/decimal" name="number" id="number"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

The validation works in the format yyyy-mm, however the day allows you to enter any number of numbers at the end. I.e 2013-06-14444444444 would get passed through. I want to restrict it purely to JUST yyyy-mm-dd. How would I go above achieving this?

Comment: I'd recommend you think about using a more robust solution, not just a regex. How about `2013-11-31`. That would be valid according to regex but it isn't a valid date. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218181/best-way-to-validate-date-string-format-via-jquery/11218271#11218271

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding a `$` at the end won't completely fix it, as you also have a `{2}` which is letting the last capture group repeat itself so instead of `yyyy-mm-dd` it is checking `yyyy-mm-ddxx`, `xx` like `dd`.

```
/^[0-9]{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]){2}$/
    .test('2013-06-1414');   // true, wait what?
```

Simply remove it to fix

```
var re = /^[0-9]{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;

re.test('2013-06-1414');     // false
re.test('2013-06-14');       // true
```

Answer (score 2):

Add '**$**' sign at the end that matches the end-of-line:

```
var dateformat=/^[0-9]{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]){2}$/;
```

Comment: To clarify why this works, the '$' at the end matches the end-of-line.

Comment: No problem - just wanted to clarify for OP.

Answer (score 1):

update the pattern line by adding a `$` at the end to specify that this is where the pattern ends:

```
var dateformat=/^[0-9]{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]){2}$/;
```